# How to group by number of bins a ordered dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a dataframe like that:**

| year | count_yes | count_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1900 | 5 | 7 |
| 1903 | 5 | 3 |
| 1915 | 14 | 6 |
| 1919 | 6 | 14 |

I want to have two bins, independently of the value itself.

How can I group those categories and sum its values?

**Expected result:**

| year | count_yes | count_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1900 | 10 | 10 |
| 1910 | 20 | 20 |

Logic: Grouped the first two rows (1900 and 1903) and the two last rows (1915 and 1919) and summed the values of each category

I want to create a stacked percentage column graphic, so 1900 would be 50/50% and 1910 would be also 50/50%.

I've already created the function to build this graphic, I just need to adjust the dataframe size into bins to create a better distribution and visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bin the years with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and aggregate with [`groupby`+`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
bins = list(range(1900, df['year'].max()+10, 10))
group = pd.cut(df['year'], bins=bins, labels=bins[:-1], right=False)

df.drop('year', axis=1).groupby(group).sum().reset_index()
```

If you only want to specify the number of bins, compute `group` with:

```
group = pd.cut(df['year'], bins=2, right=False)
```

output:

```
   year  count_yes  count_no
0  1900         10        10
1  1910         20        20
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do what you need, if you are ok using the decades as index:

```
df['year'] = (df.year//10)*10
df_group   = df.groupby('year').sum()
```

Output>>>

```
df_group

       count_yes    count_no
year        
1900          10          10
1910          20          20
```